# How do i use CONCAT in the WHERE clause to join a string and a table name in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Something in the line of

```
SELECT id, value FROM table WHERE name='prefix'+name;
```

or

```
SELECT id, value FROM table WHERE name=CONCAT('prefix',name);
```

given that name as used above is a column name

Comment: include sample data and expected output?

Comment: `SELECT id, value FROM table WHERE the_column = 'prefix' || name;`